# Setting default user locale in Tapestry session without URL

Tags: tapestry

I want to use the ApplicationStateManager in tapestry to retrieve a UserProfile  SessionState object which will include the users preferred locale. I then want to use this locale to set the ThreadLocale value for every request thus eliminating the need for the ugly URL locale value. I have the following code in my app module:

```
@Decorate(serviceInterface = ThreadLocale.class)    
    public ThreadLocale decorateThreadLocale(final ThreadLocale threadLocale, final PersistentLocale persistentLocale,
    @InjectService("ApplicationStateManager")
    ApplicationStateManager asm) {
        return new ThreadLocale() {

            @Override
            public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
                threadLocale.setLocale(locale);
            }

            @Override
            public Locale getLocale()  {
                if (!persistentLocale.isSet())
                {
                    UserProfile profile = asm.get(UserProfile.class);
                    Locale userLocale = userProfile.getPreferredLocale(); 
                    if( userLocale != null)
                        setLocale(userLocale);
                }
                return threadLocale.getLocale();
            }
        };
    }
```

The issue is that the ApplicationStateManager instance is not provided, thus it's unusable. How do I access the ApplicationStateManager from within my module?